# Проблема с XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml

Есть xml файл, пытаюсь считать его `XmlReader`

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(pathToXmlFile))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing(name))
            {}
        }
}
```

получаю ошибку вида

> Знак "»", шестнадцатеричное значение 0xBB, не может использоваться в
>   именах., строка 3, позиция 7.

фрагмент xml с 3 строки

```
  <СлЧаст>
    <ИдФайл>
```

С исходным файлом проблем нет, но после того как я его обрабатываю и получаю по сути копию (на первой итерации) - появляется данная ошибка. Из примера ниже убрал логику обработки xml, так как на первой итерации она не используется

```
    public static void Read(string tag_name, string patch_to_input_file, string patch_to_output_file)
    {
        var rs = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            IgnoreWhitespace = true
        };
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true
        };

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(patch_to_input_file, rs))
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(patch_to_output_file, ws))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
//этот if на первой итерации выполняется всегда
                            if (!HandleElement(reader, writer, tag_name))
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                                {
                                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                        case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                            writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                            writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                            writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                        case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                            writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                            writer.WriteDocType(reader.Name, reader.GetAttribute("PUBLIC"), reader.GetAttribute("SYSTEM"), reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                            writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

И вызываю так `Read("", input, output);` На выходе получаю копию исходной xml, но при попытке ее прочитать - описанная ошибка.

Comment: Какая кодировка у xml-файла? Какая кодировка указана в самом xml-файле в тэге `<?xml ... ?>`?

Comment: @Dmitry у xml стоит windows-1251

Comment: По-моему, у вас ошибка внутри условия `if`: райтером закрывается элемент. При этом ридер не продвигается дальше. А на следующей интерации `reader.Read()` доходит до закрывающего элемента и райтер повторно запишет его в блоке `case XmlNodeType.EndElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в этой части была

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
    var subTreeReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
    if (HandleElement(reader, writer, tag_name))
    {
        ReadToEnd(subTreeReader);
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
        writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
    break;
```

и дополнительно используем

```
private static void ReadToEnd(XmlReader reader)
{
    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }
}
```

и собственно

```
private static bool HandleElement(XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer)
{
    if (reader.Name == "e")
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("element", "val1");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```